# port native C++ non static binary on Android

Tags: c++, android, native, port

Im quite new on Android and I have some question for all of you who are experts!
Ok, my problem...
I implemented a client-server application based on socket programming. The server encode some packets, send them to the client through a socket and the clinet decode them.
I tested the code with two linux machines and it works fine but in my experiment it is required to include another node (this will be the Android). So the server (linux machine) will encode the packets and send through socket to client1(linux machine) and client2(Android).
For this reason I want to port the native binary of my code (which is in C++) to Android.
In which way could I do this?

Please give me some help!
Really im totally stucked!

Thanks,

Zenia

Answer (score 1):

when you want to port native code C/C++ to android you want to look up android ndk and jni

http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html

There are some examples in the ndk on how to do this.

be warned that C is fully supported but C++ support apis is very limited on android (the list is in the docs of the ndk) so you might have problems porting your code.

I would recommend using directly java if you can, since working with JNI is tedious lol

Answer (score 0):

how else can you port this? start learning android i did a quick check noticed it's sdk uses java you can start by looking at

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply,

I first tried to write my own code totally in java using sockets, however i had to port some optimized libraries to Android and I could figure out how to do that (i could port a simple small library but not the one that I wanted). I gave up and I right now im trying to play with jni and ndk. however i dont know if indeed i could port my binary as it is non static (like hello world). Thats why im asking. if anyone else have some experince on that please let me know. thanks a lot,

Zenia

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer; did you intend to add a comment instead?

Answer (score 0):

What you should probably do is install the SDK and NDK and build the hello-jni ndk example.

Then look up how to access the android logcat output from C, and write yourself a nice little printf-like wrapper for that (probably using the vargs version of the underlying function) so you can easily generate debug output from your native code.

Then graft your native executable onto the hello-jni example code, so you'll have a java wrapper that does very little other than start things with a call to the native code.  Just remember not to do much processing in the UI thread or native code called under that thread, or you will risk an application not responding timeout.

It is also possible to (ab)use the ndk's gcc to produce stand alone native executables with no java wrapper, but this is discouraged.  It's hard to find a reliable place to install them on a non-rooted phone, and android's process management isn't happy about unknown native processes.  In other words, that's a path that's fine for personal experiments on your own device, but a difficult and non-future-proof one for an application deployed to others.